# Java String contains a special Char but not even one more Char

Tags: java, regex, equals, contain

I am looking for every single URL, which is linked as "eye" in a html Document. I am using a regex pattern, because a simple contains is no solution at this point. So I got a pattern like this

Pattern:: `href=\"(https?://)?[a-zA-z0-9?/&=\"+-_\\.# ]*>[Ee]ye`

It works... fine... more or less... Because I get more than any URL linked as "Eye" or "eye". I'll get URLs which are linked as "eyebrights" or "eyewears", too, but that's not what I want.

Is there any way to say "get me this and ignore it, when there is more than I want"?

Comment: To clarify, you want any URL whose text is exactly `Eye` or `eye`? Can you not match `</a>` after eye?

Comment: Umh... I'm not sure but it sounds... logically. Damn i should have tried something like this. I will try it, thanks!

Comment: Should `eye` be first word in link description or can it be placed in the middle of text like `<a href=...>blue eye</a>`?

Comment: eye should be the first word, yes 
and i tried the </a> solution and it works, but i have some more cases where it's not enough :)
So i preferred the \b solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `\b` after  `eye`:

```
href=\"(https?://)?[a-zA-z0-9?/&=\"+-_\\.# ]*>[Ee]ye\\b
```

`\b`: assert position at a word boundary.

Comment: if want ignore `xxeye` ,then add `\\b` before `[Ee]ye`

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this! :)

Answer (score 2):

In should try to [avoid using regex to parse XML/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg). Use XML/HTML parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) instead . With this library our code could look like:

```
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]:matches(^[eE]ye\\b)");
//Elements extends ArrayList<Element> so you can easily iterate over it
```

more info at http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax